# How to increase Antd Collapse icon size and change it if collapse is expanded

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need to do two things:

1. Need to increase default icon arrow size
2. Need to change icon to a different one when the panel is expanded.

I managed to do that this way:

```
  <Collapse
  expandIconPosition='right'
  className='collapse-container'

  // this works fine
  expandIcon={({isActive}) => isActive
  ? <img src={closeCollapseIcon} />
  : <img src={openCollapseIcon} />}
  >
    <Panel header='Question...' key='3'>
      <p className='help-panel-text'>Some text</p>
    </Panel>
  </Collapse>
```

My question is:
Is there a way to do the same but in a more elegant way? My solution seems to be too straightforward.

Comment: my suggestion is to use CSS, add a class to the image and increase the width and height accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to render two img tags, you can achieve the same thing with one tag. A more appropriate way would be using the Icon component provided by ant design

```
    expandIcon={({ isActive }) => (
      <Icon
        component={isActive ? closeCollapseIcon : openCollapseIcon}
        width="2em"
        height="2em"
      />
    )}
```